# How do I write a buildspec.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have ***Java Spring web service project on EC2***

I tried writing a `buildspec.yml` for it. However the AWS CodeBuild service is not giving successful results. In the install phase itself, it tells `apt-get` and `yum` command not found. The problem is that both `yum` and `apt-get` are not being detected. However the exemplary file in the docs is using `apt-get` to in the install phase. How can I make it work?

[image: This is my buildspec file.]

I am not able to figure it out... why does it fail for both `yum` and `apt-get`?

[image: These are the logs of the build]

Comment: Both of your screenshot shows only apt-get in error... which makes sense if it's running on a RH based distribution. It's unclear what makes you think somethign with yum fail. For the future, please avoid screenshots of file content, it's harder to read and impossible to test and validate (no copy/paste possible)

Comment: Did you already try putting a "-y" for your apt-get commands?

Comment: @subinmathew Here it's `apt-get update` which is failing, it doesn't have a `-y` switch (it's ignored if present) as it never ask anything to the user.

Answer (score 7):

Few ideas to help you

1. When you define a "CodeBuild" project, you can specify which base image it will use to execute your commands. The one you are using is not Ubuntu yet you are trying `apt-get`. Try a different base image.
2. Provide us with a better log stream.

#### Exporting Logs from CloudWatch

I found that the easiest way is to export logs through command-line:

- click on 'View Logs' link, to find out your Log Group and Log Stream
- install "awscli" and "jq"

Run substituting your log-group-name and -log-stream-name:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/codebuild/Dumper  \
    --log-stream-name 0bd74b8c-74b9-4f9b-b275-167b45901aa3 | \
    jq '.events[].message' -r | grep -v '^$'
```

This should give you the output, which you can include in the question.